# Why do we use a continuous verb after "adjective + of", e.g. "I am capable of running 10k" or "I am scared of sleeping in the dark"?

Tags: prepositions, present-continuous

Why do we use a continuous verb after "adjective + of",

e.g. "I am capable of running 10k"

or "I am scared of sleeping in the dark"?

When we use "to" instead we do not, e.g. "I am scared to sleep in the dark"-- why is there a change from continuous to present for the verb?

Comment: These '-ing' words are not the continuous tense (as in _I am running_), but the gerund/participle, as James explains in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

"of" is a preposition, and generally the complement of a preposition can be either a noun phrase, a content clause or a participle-gerund.

In these cases it is idiomatic to use a participle-gerund.  The gerund form is "running". It would not be correct to have an unmarked finite clause, or a finite predicate, as the object of a preposition. It would be incorrect to say  *"I am capable of run 10k" It is also generally incorrect to say *"I am capable of run to 10k"

Comment: I think you meant "preposition" instead of "pronoun". Am I then correct in assuming that the following sentences use "run 10K" and "run to 10K" as examples of "unmarked finite clauses"?

Comment: Yes, preposition, thank-you..  A finite clause is something like "I run 10k".

Comment: OK, so then the examples in the last sentence do not demonstrate the issue mentioned in the previous sentence ("an unmarked finite clause as the object of a preposition"). Sorry, I was just a bit confused by that when I first read it.

Comment: "run 10k" is a finite predicate, Is this edit better?

Comment: That makes more sense to me, thanks! (Sorry to quibble.)